# Vuforia (Unity) Area Target as a prefab instead of an additive scene

Tags: unity-game-engine, vuforia

I'm developing a project that uses Area Target for real life navigation in different large areas. Since the project is meant to work with multiplayer through Photon engine, and that doesn't work with loading multiple scenes, I'm being forced to create prefabs of the different Area Targets so the selected one can instantiate during runtime. So far it seems to manage to recognize but the objects that I've placed in that Area Target doesn't stay in their places moving alonside the camera.

[This is the expected behavior that I get in the editor](https://www.dropbox.com/scl/fi/zagxz9h60pcuf5eirh6zm/ExpectedBehaviour.mp4?rlkey=l5upzmam2xai74tj0qd7rt6bw&dl=0)

[This is the behavior I get in an Android Samsung Galaxy S21 5G](https://www.dropbox.com/scl/fi/x0quqhf69crxjtt4wenqh/CurrentBehaviour.mp4?rlkey=slaep1205xmoqex5wcc5a5gl5&dl=0)

In previous tests, I've made it work when loading the whole thing as an additive scene. This is the structure of the prefab:

[image: Prefab Area Target]

What am I missing in order to be able to make work the Area Target as a prefab? Has anyone worked with Area Target as prefabs before? Is it even possible to make an Area Target work in a prefab?